# How to get the nested array

Tags: javascript

I have an array with nested object and I want to get only the nested object.

```js
const array = 
      [ { name: 'Allan'
        , work: 
          [ { number: 1, remarks: 'Done'       } 
          , { number: 5, remarks: 'Done'       } 
          , { number: 3, remarks: 'Incomplete' } 
      ] } ]
```

My desired array is;

```js
const desiredArray = 
      [ { number: 1, remarks: 'Done'      } 
      , { number: 5, remarks: 'Done'      } 
      , { number: 3, remarks: 'Incomplete'} 
      ]
```

What I have tried is

```js
const tried = array[0].work
```

But the result is:

```js
const undesiredArray = 
      [ [ { number: 1, remarks: 'Done'} 
        , { number: 5, remarks: 'Done'} 
        , { number: 3, remarks: 'Incomplete'} 
      ] ]
```

Comment: No, `const tried = array[0].work` does not result in your `undesiredArray` unless there is code or data you are not showing us.

Comment: You also do not specify if you only want work from a single "name" or all work from all names in a single array.

Comment: There must be some code which is putting `array[0].work` in to another array, what you have tried should work. there is no need of map function like answers showing if you're not facing any reference related issue

Comment: Angular does computation gathered from DB. When I console.log, the array is really  similar to the one in question. I don't understand what happened. Maybe its my code. I don'tunderstand no :(

Answer (score 1):

this should give u the right output

`array.map(it => it.work)`

Comment: I am using angular and I have [Array(0)]

Comment: If I click on  [Array(0)], then shows up my desiredArray

Answer (score 0):

a simple Array.map on `array[0].work`:

```js
const array = 
      [ { name: 'Allan'
        , work: 
          [ { number: 1, remarks: 'Done'       } 
          , { number: 5, remarks: 'Done'       } 
          , { number: 3, remarks: 'Incomplete' } 
      ] } ] 
      
const desiredArray = array[0].work.map(el=>el)

console.log( desiredArray )
```

Comment: how const desiredArray = array[0].work is different from your const desiredArray = array[0].work.map(el=>el) ?, there is no need of map function

Comment: @AbhaySehgal the first make a reference to `array[0].work` the second make a copy

Comment: Maybe it's my code with how I gather the array. The frontend does computation and if I do console.log, then it is really similar to the array in my question here. What if I change my question, how do I delete [ ] from [ [ { }, { } ] ] to make it [ { } , { } ] ] ?

Comment: @Mister Jojo As per the question, i don't think there is a reference issue, I think the question is incomplete. there is some code which is putting `array[0].work` into another array

Comment: @AbhaySehgal I Think too, his question is incomplete

Comment: @LeoGarcia add the context, and his it an Angular question? if so you have used a wrong tag

Answer (score 0):

Your first try should work fine, your undesired output never happen,
you probably need to debug our input, maybe is not the same as u mention in the question

```js
const array = [
{ name: 'Allan', work: [{number: 1, remarks: 'Done'}, {number: 5, remarks: 'Done'}, {number: 3, remarks: 'Incomplete'}] },
];
console.log(array[0].work);
```

i try this and it always give your desired result, so I suspect your array

Comment: Maybe its really my code because angular does frontend computation of the array. How about if I will change the question to: how do I delete [ ] from [ [ { }, { } ] ] to make it [ { } , { } ] ] ?

Comment: it cant, cause it will error, ur desired result is not enclosed  ur array correctly, or do u mean  [{ },{ }]?

Comment: if it is, then just take the index 0 of that outer array, or you can go with flatMap